# Pandas to extract Directory data into tabular form

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

Hi I have a data generated from the Directory which data information such as `name`, `email`, `project dir structure` and `cost center` etc, i want that to be extracted in a tablular form by using pandas, i am trying to out my best but could not figure out how to do that.

**MY raw Data:**

```
dn: cn=teja_rafoo,ou=Projects,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
costCenter: KR000001
LLCResponsible: cn=llcq05075,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
fullName: Entertainment account
LLCAutoSudoRole: cn=teja_rafoo,ou=Auto,ou=Sudoers,ou=Global,o=Services
LLCSecurityLevel: 0
LLCSecDom: cn=LLC,ou=SecurityDomains,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
LLCEndDate: 20000000
mail: jhaboo.udalt@LLC.com
LLCObjectType: ProjectAccount
LLCHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=LLC_EMEA_NL-LDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLC#0#Quality=ScratchHP,NisMap=LLC4008:/proj/LLC4008_teja_rafoo_cache/q,Quota=20,Id=cache
LLCHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=LLC_EMEA_NL-LDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLC#0#Quality=BusinessCriticalHP,Quota=50,NisMap=LLC3008:/proj/LLC3008_teja_rafoo/q
LLCSecurityDomain: cn=LLC,ou=SecurityDomains,ou=Global,o=Services
loginShell: /bin/bash
sn: teja_rafoo
cn: teja_rafoo
LLCStartDate: 20200510
objectClass: Top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: LLCUserAuxClass
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: Person
LLCPrimaryGroup: cn=teja_rafoo,ou=Generic,ou=Group,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
homeDirectory: /home/teja_rafoo
LLCRequestorGroup: cn=Default,ou=Requestors,ou=Master,o=Services
gecos: Entertainment account
gidNumber: 2365
LLCAutoSudoEntitledUser: cn=llcmgr,ou=Functional,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
uidNumber: 9678
LLCLocalStatus: Active
uid: teja_rafoo

dn: cn=chourya_rafoo,ou=Projects,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
costCenter: KR000002
LLCResponsible: cn=llcq05075,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
fullName: Entertainment account
LLCAutoSudoRole: cn=chourya_rafoo,ou=Auto,ou=Sudoers,ou=Global,o=Services
LLCSecurityLevel: 0
LLCSecDom: cn=LLC,ou=SecurityDomains,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
LLCEndDate: 20000000
mail: jhaboo.udalt@LLC.com
LLCObjectType: ProjectAccount
LLCHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=LLC_EMEA_NL-LDC02,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLC#0#Quality=ScratchHP,NisMap=LLC4008:/proj/LLC4008_chourya_rafoo_cache/q,Quota=20,Id=cache
LLCHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=LLC_EMEA_NL-LDC02,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLC#0#Quality=BusinessCriticalHP,Quota=50,NisMap=LLC3008:/proj/LLC3008_chourya_rafoo/q
LLCSecurityDomain: cn=LLC,ou=SecurityDomains,ou=Global,o=Services
loginShell: /bin/bash
sn: chourya_rafoo
cn: chourya_rafoo
LLCStartDate: 20200510
objectClass: Top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: LLCUserAuxClass
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: Person
LLCPrimaryGroup: cn=chourya_rafoo,ou=Generic,ou=Group,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
homeDirectory: /home/chourya_rafoo
LLCRequestorGroup: cn=Default,ou=Requestors,ou=Master,o=Services
gecos: Entertainment account
gidNumber: 2365
LLCAutoSudoEntitledUser: cn=llcmgr,ou=Functional,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
uidNumber: 9678
LLCLocalStatus: Active
uid: chourya_rafoo
```

**This data has certain row which from i want to specific info:**

```
costCenter: KR000002
LLCResponsible: cn=llcq05075,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
fullName: Entertainment account
mail: jhaboo.udalt@LLC.com
LLCHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_EMEA_NL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLC#0#Quality=ScratchHP,NisMap=LLC4008:/proj/LLC4008_chourya_rafoo_cache/q,Quota=20,Id=cache
LLCHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_EMEA_NL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLC#0#Quality=BusinessCriticalHP,Quota=50,NisMap=LLC3008:/proj/LLC3008_chourya_rafoo/q
cn: chourya_rafoo
```

**Expected:**

```
costCenter      LLCResponsible          fullName                mail                    LLCHomeDirectory                        Location

KR000001        llcq05075               Entertainment account   jhaboo.udalt@LLC.com    /proj/LLC4008_teja_rafoo_cache/q        LLC_EMEA_NL-LDC01
                                                                                        /proj/LLC3008_teja_rafoo/q
KR000002        llcq05076               Entertainment account   jhaboo.udalt@LLC.com    /proj/LLC4008_chourya_rafoo_cache/q     LLC_EMEA_NL-LDC02
                                                                                        /proj/LLC3008_chourya_rafoo/q
```

**EDIT To the Post as per comment for more clarification:**

Now as there is lot of data hence i now pulled only the required data so,  we can get into it easiluy without confusion.

Now there are only 5 fields..

- costCenter
- mail
- LLpResponsible
- LLpHomeDirectory
- fullName

**Now the Data looks like:**

```
costCenter: LL63238012
mail: shiva.gowni@LLp.com
LLpResponsible: cn=LLf58420,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLP
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=economy,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_ziz1/q,Quota=10621
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=scratKG,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_ziz1_scratKG/q,Quota=12000,Id=scratKG
fullName: Tulip project ziz1

costCenter: MX61FRK604
mail: ali.pina@LLp.com
LLpResponsible: cn=LLa11826,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLP
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_AMEC_MX-GDL01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=reference,NisMap=llc0156:/proj/llc0156_zmx28home_3/q,Quota=100,Id=3
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_AMEC_MX-GDL01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=reference,NisMap=llc0156:/proj/llc0156_zmx28home/q,Quota=300
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_AMEC_MX-GDL01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=reference,NisMap=llc0156:/proj/llc0156_zmx28home_2/q,Quota=100,Id=2
fullName: xFSL to LLDI migration

costCenter: RU61FPD561
mail: udi.landen@LLp.com
LLpResponsible: cn=LLa09278,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLP
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quota=1,Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc2002:/proj/llc2002_zru12/q
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quota=2800,Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_zru12_analog/q,Id=analog
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quota=1100,Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_zru12_home/q,Id=home
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_zru12_libddk/q,Quota=2162,Id=libddk
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_zru12_proj/q,Quota=1102,Id=proj
fullName: zru12

costCenter: KG63010285
mail: adam.smith@LLp.com
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_EMEA_NL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=BLLinessCriticalHP,Quota=60,NisMap=llc4008:/proj/llc4008_zuriKG/q
fullName: Container to store ZuriKG vault

costCenter: KG63010285
mail: adam.smith@LLp.com
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_EMEA_NL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=EconomyHP,Quota=1,NisMap=llc3008:/proj/llc3008_zuriKG_rme/q
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_EMEA_NL-RME01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=EconomyHP,Quota=30,NisMap=llc4014:/proj/llc4014_zuriKG_rme/q
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_EMEA_NL-RME01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=ScratKGHP,Quota=400,NisMap=llc4014:/proj/llc4014_zuriKG_rme_scratKG/q,Id=scratKG
fullName: Project to restore  project data on the RME work on HP-UX
```

Please help.

Comment: I updated my answer to match your despired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Format Specifications

Your format is not standard but seems to be sufficiently organized and consistent to be parsed easily. Let's assume the format is as follow:

- Record are separated by two newlines;
- Records are collections properties expressed as key value pairs separated by a single newline;
- Property key value pair are separated by `:` .

Additionally, it seems we may expect:

- Value to contains `:`  as well;
- Extra new lines separating the records or at the end of the file.

### Initial version

I'll suggest to parse it in two steps.

First we write a generator that will consume your file:

```
def generate(file):
    with open(file) as handler:
        for record in handler.read().split("\n\n"):
            result = {}
            for line in record.split("\n"):
                key, value, *_ = line.split(": ")  # Adapted on OP comment
                if key in result:
                    result[key] += ";" + value
                else:
                    result[key] = value
            yield result
```

Then, once we have loaded your data into a `DataFrame`:

```
frame = pd.DataFrame(generate("llc-data.txt"))
```

We can take advantages of Pandas series bound string functions such as regular expressions:

```
frame["responsible"] = frame["LLCResponsible"].str.extract("cn=([\w]*)")
frame["location"] = frame["LLCHomeDirectory"].str.extract("ou=([\w_\-]*)")
frame["directory"] = frame["LLCHomeDirectory"].str.findall("NisMap=\w+:([\w_\-/]*)")
```

Which produce the expected results:

```
frame[["costCenter", "responsible", "location", "directory", "fullName", "mail"]]

#   costCenter responsible           location                                          directory               fullName                      mail  
# 0   KR000001   llcq05075  LLC_EMEA_NL-LDC01  [/proj/LLC4008_teja_rafoo_cache/q, /proj/LLC30...  Entertainment account     jhaboo.udalt@LLC.com  
# 1   KR000002   llcq05075  LLC_EMEA_NL-LDC02  [/proj/LLC4008_chourya_rafoo_cache/q, /proj/LL...  Entertainment account     jhaboo.udalt@LLC.com
```

Where I have renamed computed columns in order to keep original data untouched for further extraction.

The advantage of this two steps process is that you don't need to adapt your file parser each time you want to extract more information from your file. Now it is just about to implement your additional logic in term of DataFrame manipulations which is decoupled from the file loading step.

If you need extra information later on, then just add a new column:

```
frame["username"] = frame["LLCAutoSudoRole"].str.extract("cn=([\w]*)")
```

Additionaly, if you need as much rows as directories, then just explode it:

```
frame.explode("directory")[["costCenter", "responsible", "directory"]]

#   costCenter responsible                            directory
# 0   KR000001   llcq05075     /proj/LLC4008_teja_rafoo_cache/q
# 0   KR000001   llcq05075           /proj/LLC3008_teja_rafoo/q
# 1   KR000002   llcq05075  /proj/LLC4008_chourya_rafoo_cache/q
# 1   KR000002   llcq05075        /proj/LLC3008_chourya_rafoo/q
```

### Second version after OP update

This snippet cope with the change of trial dataset you have posted.
I also have added extra newlines to highlight for sake of reproducibility.

Your final problem is probably due to extra newline at the end of the file.
Hence the need of having a way to accurately reproduce inputs.

This new version is resistant to extra newlines and extra field separator in values.

```
import pandas as pd

data = """costCenter: LL63238012
mail: shiva.gowni@LLp.com
LLpResponsible: cn=LLf58420,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLP
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=economy,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_ziz1/q,Quota=10621
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=scratKG,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_ziz1_scratKG/q,Quota=12000,Id=scratKG
fullName: Tulip project ziz1

costCenter: MX61FRK604
mail: ali.pina@LLp.com
LLpResponsible: cn=LLa11826,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLP
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_AMEC_MX-GDL01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=reference,NisMap=llc0156:/proj/llc0156_zmx28home_3/q,Quota=100,Id=3
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_AMEC_MX-GDL01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=reference,NisMap=llc0156:/proj/llc0156_zmx28home/q,Quota=300
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_AMEC_MX-GDL01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=reference,NisMap=llc0156:/proj/llc0156_zmx28home_2/q,Quota=100,Id=2
fullName: xFSL to LLDI migration



costCenter: RU61FPD561
mail: udi.landen@LLp.com
LLpResponsible: cn=LLa09278,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLP
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quota=1,Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc2002:/proj/llc2002_zru12/q
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quota=2800,Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_zru12_analog/q,Id=analog
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quota=1100,Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_zru12_home/q,Id=home
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_zru12_libddk/q,Quota=2162,Id=libddk
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_AMEC_LL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=EconomyHP,NisMap=llc1002:/proj/llc1002_zru12_proj/q,Quota=1102,Id=proj
fullName: zru12

costCenter: KG63010285
mail: adam.smith@LLp.com
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_EMEA_NL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=BLLinessCriticalHP,Quota=60,NisMap=llc4008:/proj/llc4008_zuriKG/q
fullName: Container to store ZuriKG vault



costCenter: KG63010285
mail: adam.smith@LLp.com
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=RDC_EMEA_NL-CDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=EconomyHP,Quota=1,NisMap=llc3008:/proj/llc3008_zuriKG_rme/q
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_EMEA_NL-RME01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=EconomyHP,Quota=30,NisMap=llc4014:/proj/llc4014_zuriKG_rme/q
LLpHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=SAT_EMEA_NL-RME01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLP#0#Quality=ScratKGHP,Quota=400,NisMap=llc4014:/proj/llc4014_zuriKG_rme_scratKG/q,Id=scratKG
fullName: Project to restore  project data on the RME work on HP-UX


"""


def generate(data):
    for record in data.split("\n\n"):              # Split records based on two newlines (unix)
        result = {}
        for line in record.split("\n"):            # Split properties based on single newlines (unix)
            if line:                               # Skip empty lines happening for extra or trailing newlines
                key, *value = line.split(": ")     # Tolerant to lines with more than a single ´: ´ (*values)
                value = ": ".join(value)           # Recover original value if more than a single (`: `)
                if key in result:
                    result[key] += ";" + value
                else:
                    result[key] = value
        if result:                                 # Don't yield empty results
            yield result


frame = pd.DataFrame(generate(data))

frame["responsible"] = frame["LLpResponsible"].str.extract("cn=([\w]*)")
frame["location"] = frame["LLpHomeDirectory"].str.extract("ou=([\w_\-]*)")
frame["directory"] = frame["LLpHomeDirectory"].str.findall("NisMap=\w+:([\w_\-/]*)")
```

Which produce the expected result:

```
frame[["costCenter", "responsible", "directory"]]

#    costCenter responsible                                          directory
# 0  LL63238012    LLf58420  [/proj/llc1002_ziz1/q, /proj/llc1002_ziz1_scra...
# 1  MX61FRK604    LLa11826  [/proj/llc0156_zmx28home_3/q, /proj/llc0156_zm...
# 2  RU61FPD561    LLa09278  [/proj/llc2002_zru12/q, /proj/llc1002_zru12_an...
# 3  KG63010285         NaN                           [/proj/llc4008_zuriKG/q]
# 4  KG63010285         NaN  [/proj/llc3008_zuriKG_rme/q, /proj/llc4014_zur...
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer but its giving and error like `File "file1", line 16, in generate key, value = line.split(": ")`  and  `ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)`.

Comment: The code run without error on the data you have provided. Anyway I have adapted the parsing function to cope with line having more than `: ` even if it breaks somehow the format that we could infer from the sample your provided.

Comment: The error your are facing is most probably due to deviation of your data. If you locate which records make the logic crashes and post it we can think about it. Also you can review the format proposal at the beginning of my answer and confirm all assumptions are correct. Cheers.

Comment: Yes but I am not splitting on colon, I am splitting on colon+space. The other answer also use this logic. The code works on data you have provided and the update version work on ill defined line as well. Your problem is that your file contains a record with more than colon+space in a line which is not visible on your sample. First run the code on the sample to confirm that it works with data you have provided. Then try on your real data while logging records until finding which record deviates. Update your post with the faulty records and we will see what can be done.

Comment: For me the code does not work and returns same error even with sample data.

Comment: Just trying to help. The code runs perfectly on the data you have provided. Have a good day

Comment: Well reading your comment in chat I can see that you are using this code to read a JSON format which is not what you have provided as trial data. Indeed no answer here are parsing JSON as you never provided your data in such a format. Read [mcve] and my previous comment about reviewing the format assumption. Then we will be able to go further.

Comment: Ah..thats just the output of the function you written as i put `print` statement to your `yeild` to see the data.

Comment: Could you confirm your file does fullfil the assumption stated in the beginning of my answer?

Comment: Also could you confirm which kind of newlines your file contains? Carriage return, new line, both?

Comment: I just verified the file and its always `newline` which returns unix style `$` on check. However answer to your comment `records are separated by 1 newline` only.

Comment: So does the assumptions are correct? If not how would you describe your format?

Comment: Let me edit my post with more summarize data and data feilds which are require  that will be easy.

Comment: As you wish, if you are not about to describe your format then we need as much as sample that there is are use cases.

Comment: I have updated my post with the exact same data which we required in the original format.

Comment: Your problem is probably due to extra newlines at the end of your file. I have adapted the logic to cope with such a case, I have added a [mcve] that exactly reproduces what we can do at best with the information you have provided. Let me know if it solved your issue. Regards, Jean

Comment: Thanks for the detailed explanation it works, however i have last query , how to read data directly from file `frame = pd.DataFrame(generate("llc-data.txt"))`  as this doesn't work.

Comment: The second version works on a string instead of a file as it was clear that I could not reproduce your file based on copy paste data in your post. Just change the generate method to take a file as input (see first version).

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import pandas as pd


def convert_str(input: str) -> list:
    """
    :param input: string
    :return: list of dict
    """
    output = []
    for i in input.split('\n\n'):  # split each double newline (start of new entry)
        buffer = {}
        for line in i.split('\n'):  # split each newline (start of new field)
            if line:
                a = line.split(': ')  # split field name : value
                if a[0] == 'LLCHomeDirectory':  # check if field is LLCHomeDirectory
                    # just keep the path. you can use regex if you want to add another library
                    a[1] = a[1].split(':')[1].split(',')[0]
                    # add column otherwise append column
                    if 'LLCHomeDirectory' in buffer:
                        buffer['LLCHomeDirectory'].append(a[1])
                    else: 
                        buffer['LLCHomeDirectory'] = [a[1]]
                elif a[0] == 'LLCResponsible':  # check if field is LLCResponsible
                    # just keep 'cn'
                    a[1] = a[1].split(',')[0][3:]
                    buffer['LLCResponsible'] = a[1]
                else:
                    buffer[a[0]] = a[1].split(',') if ',' in a[1] else a[1]  # split commas
        output.append(buffer)
    return output


data = """
dn: cn=teja_rafoo,ou=Projects,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
costCenter: KR000001
LLCResponsible: cn=llcq05075,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
fullName: Entertainment account
LLCAutoSudoRole: cn=teja_rafoo,ou=Auto,ou=Sudoers,ou=Global,o=Services
LLCSecurityLevel: 0
LLCSecDom: cn=LLC,ou=SecurityDomains,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
LLCEndDate: 20000000
mail: jhaboo.udalt@LLC.com
LLCObjectType: ProjectAccount
LLCHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=LLC_EMEA_NL-LDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLC#0#Quality=ScratchHP,NisMap=LLC4008:/proj/LLC4008_teja_rafoo_cache/q,Quota=20,Id=cache
LLCHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=LLC_EMEA_NL-LDC01,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLC#0#Quality=BusinessCriticalHP,Quota=50,NisMap=LLC3008:/proj/LLC3008_teja_rafoo/q
LLCSecurityDomain: cn=LLC,ou=SecurityDomains,ou=Global,o=Services
loginShell: /bin/bash
sn: teja_rafoo
cn: teja_rafoo
LLCStartDate: 20200510
objectClass: Top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: LLCUserAuxClass
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: Person
LLCPrimaryGroup: cn=teja_rafoo,ou=Generic,ou=Group,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
homeDirectory: /home/teja_rafoo
LLCRequestorGroup: cn=Default,ou=Requestors,ou=Master,o=Services
gecos: Entertainment account
gidNumber: 2365
LLCAutoSudoEntitledUser: cn=llcmgr,ou=Functional,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
uidNumber: 9678
LLCLocalStatus: Active
uid: teja_rafoo

dn: cn=chourya_rafoo,ou=Projects,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
costCenter: KR000002
LLCResponsible: cn=llcq05075,ou=Personal,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
fullName: Entertainment account
LLCAutoSudoRole: cn=chourya_rafoo,ou=Auto,ou=Sudoers,ou=Global,o=Services
LLCSecurityLevel: 0
LLCSecDom: cn=LLC,ou=SecurityDomains,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
LLCEndDate: 20000000
mail: jhaboo.udalt@LLC.com
LLCObjectType: ProjectAccount
LLCHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=LLC_EMEA_NL-LDC02,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLC#0#Quality=ScratchHP,NisMap=LLC4008:/proj/LLC4008_chourya_rafoo_cache/q,Quota=20,Id=cache
LLCHomeDirectory: nisMapName=auto.home,ou=LLC_EMEA_NL-LDC02,ou=Locations,ou=LLDI,o=LLC#0#Quality=BusinessCriticalHP,Quota=50,NisMap=LLC3008:/proj/LLC3008_chourya_rafoo/q
LLCSecurityDomain: cn=LLC,ou=SecurityDomains,ou=Global,o=Services
loginShell: /bin/bash
sn: chourya_rafoo
cn: chourya_rafoo
LLCStartDate: 20200510
objectClass: Top
objectClass: inetOrgPerson
objectClass: LLCUserAuxClass
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: Person
LLCPrimaryGroup: cn=chourya_rafoo,ou=Generic,ou=Group,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
homeDirectory: /home/chourya_rafoo
LLCRequestorGroup: cn=Default,ou=Requestors,ou=Master,o=Services
gecos: Entertainment account
gidNumber: 2365
LLCAutoSudoEntitledUser: cn=llcmgr,ou=Functional,ou=People,ou=LLDI,o=LLC
uidNumber: 9678
LLCLocalStatus: Active
uid: chourya_rafoo
"""

final = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(convert_str(data))

# remove columns
remove_cols = ['costCenter', 'LLCResponsible', 'fullName', 'mail', 'LLCHomeDirectory', 'Location']
final = final[final.columns.intersection(remove_cols)]

print(final.to_string())
```

I took the liberty of converting comma deliminated strings to lists.

Output:

```
  costCenter LLCResponsible               fullName                  mail                                                      LLCHomeDirectory
0   KR000001      llcq05075  Entertainment account  jhaboo.udalt@LLC.com        [/proj/LLC4008_teja_rafoo_cache/q, /proj/LLC3008_teja_rafoo/q]
1   KR000002      llcq05075  Entertainment account  jhaboo.udalt@LLC.com  [/proj/LLC4008_chourya_rafoo_cache/q, /proj/LLC3008_chourya_rafoo/q]
```